# Does sizeof return the number of bytes or the number of octets of a type in C?

Tags: c, byte, sizeof, word-size

Simply put in C and variants (unlike that wuss java with its virtual machine) the size of primitive types on different targets can vary greatly, and there is really no guarantee unless you use the fixed width types defined in `stdint.h`, and even then your implemenation has to support them.

Anyway hypothetically(because on most modern machines a byte is an octet, for networking purposes I assume(ASCII)) does sizeof return the size of a datatype in bytes or in octets?

Comment: Bytes, but a single byte (represented as `char`) has `CHAR_BITS` bits. If you want the number of octets in a `T`, do `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BITS / 8`. On most platforms, `CHAR_BITS` is `8`.

Comment: @GManNickG `CHAR_BIT` (there's no S) :)

Comment: float octetPercent = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT /8.0;

Comment: Note that POSIX and Windows (i.e. basically 99.999% of non-DSP systems) both require a byte to be an octet, the the question is mostly of interest for purposes of pedantry/language-lawyering.

Comment: You've got it, that's why it says hypothetical.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answer: `sizeof` returns the size of the type in **bytes**.

---

Example: `sizeof(char)` is 100% guaranteed to be `1`, but this does not mean, that it's one octet (8 bits).

---

Proved by the standard:

in 6.5.3.4, point 2:

> **The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand**, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.
>
> ...
>
> **When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
>   (or a qualiﬁed version thereof) the result is 1**. When applied to an operand that has array
>   type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array) When applied to an operand
>   that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object,
>   including internal and trailing padding.

Also, in Section 3.6, point 3:

> A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined

Comment: What is the reason why sizeof(char) = 1?

Comment: @ConnorFuhrman It is the definition: *3.7.1: character: single-byte character* and for sizeof: *6.5.3.4  The sizeof operator: [...] When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1*

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof` always returns size as the number of bytes. But according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof):

> In the programming languages C and C++, the unary operator sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the number of bytes required to represent the type. A byte in this context is the same as an unsigned char, **and may be larger than 8 bits, although that is uncommon**.

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof` gives the size in bytes.  However, note that "byte" is a technical term in the C standard, and is defined such that `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, working on embedded micro controllers with exotic 'C' compilers, I have seen:

```
sizeof( uint8 )
```

return 1

```
sizeof( uint16 )
```

return 1

```
sizeof( uint32 )
```

return 2

Clearly, I was dealing with a machine were the smallest addressable entity was 16 bit, so the sizeof does not comply with C89 or C99.

I would say that on mainstream C89 & C99 compliant systems, the accepted answer is correct.
Unfortunately, a "C" compiler can still be called a "C" compiler, even if it does not comply to a 25 year old standard. I hope this answer help put things in perspective, given more exotic systems.

Comment: Why do you think this does not comply to the standard? If `char` is 16 bits wide this is exactly what I would expect. If the smallest addressable entity is 16-bits, it also makes sense that a `uint8_t` must occupy at least 16 bits (thus `sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(uint16_t)`).

Comment: This is a great answer, it reveals the nuances. The take home:  Check `CHAR_BIT in <limits.h>` and compare that to `sizeof(char)` for reference. Where byte in all strictly technical cases is 8bits, except when (software says it is not) `CHAR_BIT` is not equal to `8`. As `C derives its definition for byte from CHAR_BIT.` In the case of your 16bit minimum addressable size I bet `CHAR_BIT` was set to 16. Can you corroborate this?